# Symmetric Encryption with large strings returns same string but a loss of 1-5 bytes

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography

I have been playing around with an old code I wrote using SHA1 to work with SHA256 or SHA512.
I am fairly new in the cryptography world and I wondered if someone can tell me why my input value in the Encrypt method returns through the Decrypt method with a loss of 1-5 bytes.

I can run the methods with short strings no problem but apparently not larger e.g. 16 bytes +.

The two methods in Question are:

```
    public string Decrypt(string data, EncryptionValue eV, string passPhrase)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(eV.InitVector);
    byte[] rgbSalt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(eV.SaltValue);
    byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
    byte[] rgbKey = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passPhrase, rgbSalt, eV.PassIterations, hash).GetBytes(eV.KeySize / 8);

    var managed = Aes.Create("AesManaged");
    managed.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    managed.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    ICryptoTransform transform = managed.CreateDecryptor(rgbKey, bytes);
    MemoryStream stream = new(buffer);
    CryptoStream stream2 = new(stream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
    byte[] buffer5 = new byte[buffer.Length];
    int count = stream2.Read(buffer5, 0, buffer5.Length);
    stream.Close();
    stream2.Close();
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer5, 0, count);
}
public string Encrypt(string data, EncryptionValue eV, string passPhrase)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(eV.InitVector);
    byte[] rgbSalt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(eV.SaltValue);
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
    byte[] rgbKey = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passPhrase, rgbSalt, eV.PassIterations, hash).GetBytes(eV.KeySize / 8);

    var managed = Aes.Create("AesManaged");
    managed.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    
    managed.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    ICryptoTransform transform = managed.CreateEncryptor(rgbKey, bytes);
    MemoryStream stream = new();
    CryptoStream stream2 = new(stream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    stream2.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    stream2.FlushFinalBlock();
    byte[] inArray = stream.ToArray();
    stream.Close();
    stream2.Close();
    return Convert.ToBase64String(inArray);
}
```

The Encryption Value Class contains randomised randomised values and it's not the issue here but I am posting it anyway here:

```
 public int PassIterations { get; set; }
 public int KeySize { get; set; }
 public string InitVector { get; set; }
 public string SaltValue { get; set; }
```

The Iterations are around 1000 in all my tests. I've done tests with less and more.
KeySize is always 256 or 128,
InitVector = "~1B2c3D4e5F6g7H8";

I ran some tests and like I said, smaller strings are okay but I want it to be able to store at least 120 bytes. I thought this would work?

Comment: You're passing something called `hash` to the constructor of `Rfc2898DerivedBytes` that isn't defined anywhere in your sample. Assuming that it is of type `HashAlgorithmName`, your code works as posted with no loss of bytes or difference between the plain text and the decrypted cipher text. See here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/p4FtMx. How are you determining there is a difference between those two values?

Comment: Yes, the has in this case is HashAlgorytmName.SHA512 or HashAlgorytmName.SHA256

Comment: I run a xUnit Test where I assert.True(result.Equals(data)) where result is the return from Decrypt() and data is the input. I always end up with a loss of some bytes e.g. "I have run a test here to tell you the answer to life is 42" where the result is:

"I have run a test here to tell you the answer to"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is actually with the `stream2.Read` call in your *Decrypt* method. The stream's Read method does NOT guarantee that it will read `buffer5.Length` bytes. It's quite possible that it reads fewer bytes than requested in a single call even without reaching the end of the stream, and thus leaving bytes unread in the stream that would still need to be read. Which is perfectly valid behavior, and whether and how this behavior materialized with respect to your code depends on how precisely a particular CryptoStream implementation (depending on the .NET version and/or host OS running your program) or configuration is behaving with regard to read operations.

You'll need to check how many bytes `stream2.Read` has read, and if it read fewer than
buffer5.Length bytes, then you'll need to call `stream2.Read` again and again until buffer5 is completely filled or `stream2.Read` is indicating end-of-stream by returning 0. A simpler solution than implementing this is perhaps by using the [`BinaryReader.ReadBytes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binaryreader.readbytes) method, which will read as many bytes as requested (unless an end-of-stream is reached before all requested bytes have been read, of course).

See this dotnetfiddle example that exposes this behavior: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ATLVTm
Note the "cheap" Console.WriteLine instrumentation i have added making this behavior visible.

P.S.: Just a nitpicky side note unrelated to your problem: Instead of manually closing all those streams, it would be better to use the `using` statement in conjunction with the streams (because streams are `IDisposable`'s) which would automatically take care of closing/disposing the streams when the respective stream variable goes out of scope, even when exceptions are being thrown by your code.

Comment: I shall look into this, sounds weird to me that the stream2.read wouldn't just read the whole thing. 

Thank you for finding this. :)

Comment: It's not weird at all, it's how streams work in general. Consider fragmented TCP traffic getting assembled bit by bit, this implementation will return however much is available when called without forcing you to (synchronously) wait for the rest.

Comment: @KaiTapper Funnily enough, on Windows i was not able to reproduce your problem. So i was set to prove you wrong in that your code is working just fine. And of course i wanted not just claim that, i wanted to provide proof by showing your code running just proper in dotnetfiddle (at that time i didn't take a closer look at your code). Imagine my surprise when, after having witnessed your code running without issues on my Windows box, the very same code running in dotnetfiddle behaved exactly like you observed and described. ;-D

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace That's the thing, I ran this code in Visual Studio using xUnit and had issues but someone running the same code somewhere else didn't have this issue. I was contemplating whether it was just me being crazy for a while there.

Comment: @KaiTapper, i just improved my dotnetfiddle example, if you are interested in (link updated in my answer). It now shows the length of the plain text i used (153 chars = 153 UTF-8 bytes, because i only used ASCII characters), and needing two stream2.Read invocations to read back those 153 bytes from the CryptoStream...

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace yes, I posted the temporary solution that fixed my problem too. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

The error was what @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace, I simply set it to check whether the buffer was fully read or not.

```
if (count < buffer5.Length)
    {
        int count2 = stream2.Read(buffer5, count, buffer5.Length - count);
        count = count + count2;
    }
```

It now passes all my xUnit Tests even if I go crazy on the string length in the data input.

Thanks for the help all involved. :)

Comment: No ;-) That's not reliable and prone to the same problem your original code suffers from, if the plaintext gets even longer. You will need to loop the  stream2.Read's until the buffer is filled (or an EOS happens). You cannot trust that the second stream2.Read to reads _all_ remaining bytes. I just did this in a linear "non-looped" manner in my dotnetfiddle to demonstrate/expose the behavior in simple to follow and understandable manner. Again, as is the case for the first Read call, there is NO guarantee that the second Read call will read all the requested (remaining) bytes.

Comment: (Maybe what i did in my dotnetfiddle was an ill-advised attempt at simplicity and i should use looped Read calls there too. Hmm...)

Comment: Yes, in the next version I will make sure to loop through until the stream2 is fully read. :) But now when I know where the problem lies I can at least fix it. :)