# Truncating data in decompress using GZipStream

Tags: c#, .net-core, gzipstream

I have compressed text data using below code

```
using (GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
 {
     zip.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
 }
```

Now I am trying to decompress using below code but actual text is getting truncated if text is bigger. This is happening in .NET Core 6.0 but same code returning correct data if I use in .NET Framework 4.7.2

```
byte[] gzBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(compressedText);
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
       int msgLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(gzBuffer, 0);
       ms.Write(gzBuffer, 4, gzBuffer.Length - 4);
       byte[] buffer = new byte[msgLength];
       ms.Position = 0;

       using (GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress))
       {
           zip.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
           zip.Close();
       }
       return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
   }
```

What is reason of such behavior.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: `Stream.Read` (e.g., you calling `zip.Read`) does **NOT** guarantee that buffer.Length bytes will be read in a single call. Your code needs to process the return value of the Read method to see how many bytes have been read by that call of the Read method. If less bytes than requested have been read, you'll need to repeat the Read call again and again until you either got all the bytes you need/want or the end of the stream is reached.

Comment: It's probably easier and more convenient to use BinaryReader's ReadBytes method, as it does all that busy-work i just explained. As an aside: As you are using the `using` statement on your GZipStream (correctly), the zip.Close call is not necessary, as disposing of the GZipStream (as ensured by the `using` statement will also close it.)

Comment: (FYI: See also here for the exact same problem rearing its head in a different context with a different stream type: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73530122/symmetric-encryption-with-large-strings-returns-same-string-but-a-loss-of-1-5-by/73530782)

Comment: (FYI 2: You can perhaps avoid all the stream shenanigans, if your code in your question is actually the _entire_ real code you are using for decompressing and reading the GZIP data. If so, in effect you _only_ and exlusively obtain UTF-8 text. And you could then significantly simplify your code by wrapping the GZipStream in a StreamReader - which by default uses UTF-8 encoding, call StreamReader's ReadToEnd method, and call it a day...)

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work without any truncation

```cs
var gzBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(compressedText);
int msgLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(gzBuffer, 0);

using (var ms = new MemoryStream(gzBytes, 4, msgLength))
using (var zip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(zip))
{
    return reader.ReadBlock();
}
```

This assumes that the first four bytes contain the number of bytes to read.